# DbSet remains null in a mock after set

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq

I want to create a mock (using Moq) of Entity Framework core's db context which includes `DbSets`. I want to create a mock of the context with an empty `DbSet` and then initialize it with records of my own. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
private Mock<RealDBContext> GetDbContextMock()
    {
        var realDB= new RealDBContext();                                                                
        var dbContextMock = new Mock<RealDBContext>();
        dbContextMock.SetupAllProperties();
        dbContextMock.Object.SomeTable1= realDB.SomeTable1; //here I want the real data from the real tables
        dbContextMock.Object.SomeTable2= realDB.SomeTable2; //also here I want the real data
        dbContextMock.Object.SomeTable3= dbContextMock.Object.Set<SomeTable3Model>(); // here I want to create a new and empty DbSet
        dbContextMock.Object.SomeTable3Model.AddRange(GetMockSomeTable3ModelList());
        return dbContextMock;
    }
```

After the line with the `Set` I've expected to get a new and empty `DbSet`, but it remains null. How do I create a new and empty DbSet?

Comment: What methods do you want to use. You'll want to do something like dbContextMock.Setup(o => o.Set<Type>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Type, bool>>()>()).Returns(CallbackMethod). Then have that callbackmethod return something from a list of that type. Not on my dev machine at the moment, so can't write up a working example. Setup before calling "dbContextMock.Object"

Comment: @Monofuse I'm trying to set the properties of the mock object such that in the test the values are set will be used - meaning I'm simply trying to mock the DbSet properties which the context have

Comment: and if I understand you correctly and you suggest to mock the set to return my needed DbSet, there's still a problem of creating it since DbSet is an abstract class

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. If you put a breakpoint on the end of the test, you can see that the list now contains what was added. You should obviously setup the mock dbset's addrange.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

#pragma warning disable EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.
        public interface IRealDbContext : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable, IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>, IDbContextDependencies, IDbSetCache, IDbContextPoolable, IResettableService
        {
            DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        }
#pragma warning restore EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var mockedContext = new Mock<IRealDbContext>();

            var persons = new List<Person>();
            var mockedPersonSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();
            mockedPersonSet.Setup(o => o.Add(It.IsAny<Person>())).Callback(new Action<Person>(person => persons.Add(person)));

            mockedContext.Setup(o => o.Persons).Returns(mockedPersonSet.Object);

            mockedContext.Object.Persons.Add(new Person()
            {
                Name = "John Smith"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does adding to a local list mocks the dbset itself? What happens when I need to query from the dbset? That local list won't be available for the class I test